# inputFile causing unauthorized error on sites page

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, apexinputfile

I have a site that I want to use to upload files to users accounts.

I already have the site up and running and it can push data into salesforce and create records.

I am now trying to use an apex:inputFile in the page so users can upload files to the account.

When I add this and then call my upload method I get an unauthorized message. I have checked permissions and cannot find anything relating to attachments. I have ticked the "Allow site guest users to upload files" box.

Code is as follows:

**Page** (I have removed other fields, images etc but nothing that affects this issue.)

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" standardStyleSheets="false" controller="CustomPortalController">
<html>
<body>
<apex:form>
  <apex:actionFunction name="trainingConf" action="{!trainingConf}"/>
  <table>
    <tr>            
      <td>Please attach PO here: </td>
      <td><apex:inputfile value="{!poBlob}" filename="PO.pdf"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><apex:commandbutton action="{!insertAttachment}" value="Confirm Booking" oncomplete="trainingConf();"></apex:commandbutton>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</apex:form>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**
(Other things happen in this controller that I have removed but don't affect this issue)

```
public class CustomPortalController {

    public Attachment attach {get;set;}
    public transient Blob poBlob {get; set;}

public PageReference insertAttachment(){
    String oppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); 
               
    attach.parentId = oppId;
    attach.name = 'POName.pdf';
    attach.body = poBlob;
    insert attach;
        
    return null;
    }

public pageReference trainingConf(){
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/TrainingConf');
    pageRef.setRedirect(false);

    return pageRef;
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried using without sharing? Struggling to find it but sure I read something specifically about site users and inputfile in the recent site security changes.

Comment: I've just tried adding that but it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the resource I was thinking of: https://www.learnexperiencecloud.com/s/news/everything-you-need-to-know-about-securing-public-sites-on-community-cloud-20Y1U000000UkRSUA0 unfortunately not loading...but got there via https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F93A0000004mDISAY?